# Data Normalisation cannot reach 3nf

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization

Hi I'm currently trying to normalise my data from a scenario through to 3NF. Have got this far but not really sure if its correct as I don't really know how to proceed from 2nf to 3nf ... any help would be much appreciated.

UNF

```
* Property ID
* Weekly Rate
* Property Type (repeating)
* Location (Repeating)
* owner (repeating)
* owner address (repeating)
* no of rooms (repeating)
* kitchen(repeating)
```

1NF

```
* Property ID (PK)
* Weekly Rate

----------


* Owner (PK)
* Property ID (FK)
* Location
* Property Type
* Owner Address
* No Of Rooms
* Kitchen
```

2NF

```
* Property ID (PK)
* Weekly Rate


----------


* Owner (PK)
* Property ID (FK)
* Owner Address


----------


* Property ID (PK)
* Location
* Property Type
* No of Rooms
* Kitchen
```

this is as far as i have got not really sure how to get this into 3nf and not sure if having property ID as the (PK) in two tables is correct?

Comment: hi I'm working from a form ... for example I have been given an 'accommodation specification form' and have been told to extract the data from their (the list called UNF) and then just normalise the data from that list above. Im not building the database you see this is just work for university.

Comment: You may be nearer 3NF than you think. Is the weekly rate a constant, or does it change according to season? Presumably 'kitchen' is a simple 'yes/no' column?

Comment: Weekly rate is a constant there is no seasonal change, and yes kitchen is a yes/no column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3NF = 2NF + no non-key attributes that depend on another non-key attribute

```
Property
-------------------
Property ID
Owner ID
Location (unknown? Beach?)
Address
Weekly Rate
Property Type
No of Rooms
Kitchen (Yay, Nay)



Owner
-------------------
Owner ID
Address
```

Comment: Normalization doesn't introduce new attributes. (You introduced "Owner ID".)

Comment: unless a property has multiple owners, Owner ID seem pretty wise here, unless one wants an unnecessary Junction table for the one owner. A lot unknown here, happy to expand upon it when needed, @MikeSherrill'CatRecall'

Comment: There *is* a lot of unknown here. What's *known*, though, is that normalization doesn't introduce new attributes.

Comment: I will try to be a better problem solver moving forward